# Yesod devel InternalError - "devel.hs: signal: 15"

Tags: haskell, yesod, haskell-stack

I have a yesod app that compiles and runs fine on my main dev machine (Ubuntu 16.04).
Today I cloned the repo on another machine running Ubuntu 18.04.
It compiles fine, however when I try to run in devel mode:

```
stack exec yesod -- devel
```

it compiles but shows the 'Application isn't built' page at localhost:3000. When I press enter to recompile I get an error like so:

```
devel.hs: runFakeHandler issue: InternalError "devel.hs: signal: 15"
CallStack (from HasCallStack):
  error, called at src/Yesod/Core/Unsafe.hs:24:14 in yesod-core-1.6.14-8UP8zoy9zgT7ImCVVtHxpr:Yesod.Core.Unsafe
Success! Waiting for next file change.
Type help for available commands. Press enter to force a rebuild.
Starting devel application
Devel application launched: http://localhost:3000
Made application.
```

As you can see, it then says the build was successful, and waits for changes. 
localhost:3000 still shows the 'application isn't built' page.

I have tried:

- removing and reinstalling latest stack, yesod-bin etc.
- deleting ~/.stack and .stack-work and recompiling everything
- checked that libs such as postgres-dev, sqlite3, zlib1g-dev, etc. exist

Can anyone give me any clues as to what this error means and what to try next?

System:

- Ubuntu 18.04 running kernal 4.15.0-72-generic x64
- stack 2.1.3
- yesod-bin 1.6.0.3
- ghc 8.6.4

Thanks for any help!

**Update**: Based on the first comment I have tried

```
stack exec -- yesod devel
```

as well as

```
yesod devel
```

All three invocations result in the same behaviour and error described above on the 18.04 machine, and all three work as expected on the 16.04 machine. Therefore I don't think it's about how yesod's dev mode is being called.

Finally, the compiled app works correctly when I call it with

```
stack exec my-app -- settings.yml
```

so this seems to be specifically about yesod devel.

Comment: I'm no expert (never used Yesod and relatively new to Stack), but that output, and the command, looks a bit like you're trying to run Yesod itself as an executable. According to the [quickstart guide](https://www.yesodweb.com/page/quickstart) the command should be `stack exec -- yesod devel`, which is subtly different from the one you're running.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @Robin. You are correct that the quickstart guide has the dashes in that order, (which doesn't make no sense to me). Just to make sure, I tried both ways. On the 18.04 computer I get the same error. On the 16.04 computer it succeeds as usual. (Edit: for clarity)

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured out what was going on here.

I was using an sqlite database during development. While trying to troubleshoot something else months ago, I had set the sqlite poolsize to 1, and had not set it back.

This was causing some database inserts to block things before the server started. This only showed up in devel mode during setup of a new development database.

Setting the sqlite poolsize in settings.yml to 10 fixed things.